# Find all the solutions of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find all the solutions of the equation
$\sin^5(x) + \cos^3(x) =1.$
I tried it and get 
$(1-\cos(x))(\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x) -\cos^2(x) -1)=0$
but I have no idea how to proceed from here.
please help me to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin^5x\le\sin^2x,\cos^3x\le\cos^2x\implies\sin^5x+\cos^3x\le\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$

The equality occurs if $\sin^5x=\sin^2x$ and $\cos^3x=\cos^2x$